# Store the Id column into a variable, using Entity Framework & C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to store all the id column from a table into something that allows me to compare it with a number from a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here,Try this

```
var myvariable = myDataContext.MyTable.Select(x=>x.Id).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store `Id` value for comparing than for example `HashSet<T>` will be more efficent collection for keeping all `Id`s and comparing them to other value

```
var allIds = dataContext.YourTableable.Select(row => row.Id);

HashSet<int> idsOfYourTable = new HashSet<int>(allIds);

if(idsOfYourTable.Contains(34) == true)
{
    // do your staff
}
```